# Daf Yomi and a half-Daf

Tags: torah-study, siyum, daf-yomi

What is typically done in the Daf Yomi Shi'ur when a Masechta ends with a half-Daf (ie., an 'Amud, or single-sided page, vs. a full Daf, which is the double-sided page that is studied daily)? Is whatever is done in this instance also what is typically done when a Masechta ends with a half-'Amud?
 Usually a Shi'ur meets daily (or nightly) to learn together, and usually the Shi'ur has a predictable length, such as an hour, etc.

I'm looking for all of the following information:

1. Because of the shortened "assignment" in the daily learning, is the next half-Daf learned in the same day's Shi'ur?  Is the next full Daf learned?  Or does the day's Daf only include that half-Daf (just a shorter Shi'ur)?
2. Is a Siyum typically made immediately upon completion of that (half-)Daf?  If, instead of a shortened learning session, the Shi'ur goes forward and begins the next Daf, does the Siyum cause a break in the Shi'ur for several minutes, or does a Siyum commence later (eg., at the end of the Shi'ur)?

Comment: If the last page is very short, some shiurim will roll it into the previous day's learning and have a day off.  Here, a lot depends on when is especially convenient for the siyyum.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, only the last amud (or half-amud) of that mesechta is learned. The next day, the new mesechta is begun.

Answer (score 2):

At the Shi'ur I attended last night, the learning formally ended at the conclusion of the half-(ok, Rov-)'Amud and a Siyum commenced.  Since we were in a Sukkah, some foods were brought out and drinks were poured, at which point a Daf-Yomi beginner, who had been a regular participant in this group, walked in late.  As a service to him, and to make his first Siyum special, the half-'Amud was learned again, followed by another Hadran and Kaddish.  At this point, the Siyum became very joyous, which was quite apropos for the evening (being Zeman Simhatheinu and all).